# bind an actionresult to a button in MVC5

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I would like to run this actionresult on a button click and have it only change the document status of the document the button was clicked on however I do not know enough about AJAX, JavaScript and JQuery to achieve this and all the other question on here are rather vague on the subject I was wonder if any of you could lend a hand.

ActionResult code

```
 public ActionResult ChangeStatus(int? id)
 {
     if (id == null)
     {
         return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
     }
     Document document = db.Documents.Find(id);
     if (document.DocumentStatus == "Draft")
     {
         document.DocumentStatus = "Active";
         db.Entry(document).State = EntityState.Modified;
         db.SaveChanges();
         return View(document);
     }
     else
     {
         document.DocumentStatus = "Draft";
         db.Entry(document).State = EntityState.Modified;
         db.SaveChanges();
         return View(document);
     }
 }
```

any help you guys could give would be appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function AjaxPost(url, data, fnSuccess, fnError) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: Success,
        error: Error
    });
}


function Success() {
    console.log("Success");
}
function Error() {
    console.log("Error");
}



function ChangeStatusById() {

    AjaxPost("/ControllerName/ChangeStatus", {
        Id: id
    }, Success, Error);
}
```

> You must take id via jQuery;

```
var id = $('#id').val();
```

And add `[HttpPost]` attribute to your controller.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using native Razor syntax in a view.  Buttons are used frequently with forms so you'd have something like this:

```
<h3>Some HTML/Razor stuff up here...</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeStatus", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "docId" }))
{
<input type="submit" value="Click Me!" />
}
```

Make sure you update the name of your controller and also supply a valid doc id value.